# How to start a new activity class in AlertDialog popup by choosing ok button

Tags: android, button

There is first activity where users save their detail. after clicking save button an Alertdialog asking about ok or cancel . if user clicks on ok then a new activity get started.

```
    protected final Dialog onCreateDialog(final int id) {
    Dialog dialog = null;
    switch(id) {
    case DIALOG_ID:
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AppointInformation.this);
        builder.setMessage("Information saved successfully ! Add Another Info?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

startActivity(new Intent(((Dialog)dialog).getContext(),CheckPatient.class));    
          }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create(); 
        dialog = alert;
        break;

    default:

    }
    return dialog;
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

I know it's too late but I want to answer this for helping other people, this works for me :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),OtherActivity.class);
                 context.startActivity(intent);
```

context is the context of the current activiy.

Answer (score 1):

in your code change:

```
startActivity(new Intent(((Dialog)dialog).getContext(),CheckPatient.class));
```

to

```
startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(),CheckPatient.class));
```

or

```
startActivity(new Intent(Activityname.this,CheckPatient.class));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974564/how-to-start-a-new-activity-class-in-alertdialog-popup-by-choosing-ok-button  not working showing AndroidRuntime(19707): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mks.gks.sks/mks.gks.sks.CheckPatient}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null

Comment: bez you have bug in CheckPatient  Activity not in dialog

Comment: @SAURABH_12 : see ` Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mks.gks.sks/mks.gks.sks.CheckPatient}` it means you have problem in CheckPatient.java Activity system trying to start from dialog

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974564/how-to-start-a-new-activity-class-in-alertdialog-popup-by-choosing-ok-button/9974652#comment12744779_9974652   okk i m trying to find out this bug . thanks for information.

Answer (score 0):

In the ok or Cancel button click  you can write this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
   .setCancelable(false)
   .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(PresentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
       }
   })
   .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
       }
   });
 builder.show();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974564/how-to-start-a-new-activity-class-in-alertdialog-popup-by-choosing-ok-button    Not working i already try this.

Comment: check my answer now, i was added builder.show(); in code it's working now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974564/how-to-start-a-new-activity-class-in-alertdialog-popup-by-choosing-ok-button     this is the catlogerror E/AndroidRuntime(29931): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mks.gks.sks/mks.gks.sks.CheckPatient}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null

Comment: are you mentioned second activity in manifest file , other please update your question with latest code..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974564/how-to-start-a-new-activity-class-in-alertdialog-popup-by-choosing-ok-button/9974652#comment12744369_9974652    yes i mention checkpatient in manifest.xml there is some more detail of error.. E/AndroidRuntime(29931):  at mks.gks.database.DatabaseHandler.Doccode(DatabaseHandler.java:166)
 E/AndroidRuntime(29931):  at mks.gks.sks.CheckPatient.onCreate(CheckPatient.java:71)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like below for this.

```
AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidAlertDialog.this); myAlertDialog.setTitle("--- Title ---"); 
        myAlertDialog.setMessage("Alert Dialog Message");
         myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
         public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {  
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);  
        startActivity(intent);
    }}); 

        myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {  

        // do something when the Cancel button is clicked  
        }}); 

        myAlertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    alert.setTitle(title);
    alert.setCancelable(false);
    alert.setMessage(message);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this, NewActivity.class));
        }
    });
    alert.show();
```

Use above code:::

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: You cannot simply use 'this' when creating the intent from within the AlertDialog interface.